# RewriteEngine on (in .htaccess) + POST Request with C#

Tags: c#, .htaccess

I have a C# program that sends regular POST request (uploadvalues) to my website.
It works perfect.
But I just wrote following lines to my .htaccess file and my program started giving Web Request errors:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

I needed these lines so that people can not access the site like this: http://mydomain.com
(without www)

How do I make my C# program work with new .htaccess settings?

Edit:
The C# program IS using www address.
Don't see anything in server error log.
The C# exception is: "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

I assume the request goes to .htaccess before it goes anywhere else. Is it possible that it makes some delay (like some kind of millisecond interruption), that makes my program think it got bad response?

Comment: `Web Request errors` is not really a helpful error message. What is actually happening from a HTTP protocol standpoint? What response code are you getting? Is there anything in the server error logs?

Comment: That htaccess rule causes the browser to redirect if it is not on `www` so likely the C# client needs to follow the redirect, or be modified to use `www` which I'm guessing it is currently not using.

Comment: drew: you were right. I forgot about one drop-down menu that was setting up URL. works now. Thanks